# how can i boil an animated menu that opens when cursive enters and closes when cursor is removed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can do it to open the menu when I drag the cursor, but if I pull it down then I don't know how to do it to close it.
I tried onmouseou but it didn't really work because it was constantly closed when I moved the mouse
There are a few extra things in the css code

```html
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="#">123</a>
        <a href="#">123</a>
        <a href="#">123</a>
    </div>
    <span onmouseover="openNav(this)" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" >&#9776;MENÜ</span>
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```js
function openNav() {

    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

Comment: You don't need javascript for this. Look into the css `:hover` pseudo selector.

Comment: @Geuis how would you go about affecting a different node while hovering over another? Or would you try to bundle them up in a single container?

Comment: what does "boil" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong event listener. These two will get the job done:

- **mouseenter:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event
- **mouseleave:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

Also - better set the event listener in your js rather than html:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
// Listener set on menu mouse enter
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("mouseenter", ()=>{openNav()});

// Listener set on sidenav mouse leave
document.getElementById("mySidenav").addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{closeNav()});
```

just have to give the menu an id for selecting it:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">123</a>
  <a href="#">123</a>
  <a href="#">123</a>
</div>
<span id="menu" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" >&#9776;MENÜ</span>
```

Here's a link to working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/msq4ogza/4/